# matrix expression to extract multiples substrings from a string in octave

Tags: octave, substr

Given the indexes (beginning and end character) of the substrings to be extracted in an Nx2 matrix R, how to extract them from S in a cell string?

Intuitively, it would work like this:

```
octave:1> S = "123456789";
octave:2> R = [1 3; 2 5; 7 9];
octave:3> msubstr(S, R)
ans =
{"123", "2345", "789"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrayfun:

```
S = "123456789";
R = [1 3; 2 5; 7 9];
octave> arrayfun (@(s,e) S(s:e), R(:,1), R(:,2), "UniformOutput", false)
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = 123
  [2,1] = 2345
  [3,1] = 789
}
```

You could also define your own function for this:

```
function ret = msubstr (S, R)
  ret = arrayfun (@(s,e) S(s:e), R(:,1), R(:,2), "UniformOutput", false);
endfunction
```